# I don't understand what's happening when I merge to a repository from a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

So as per company policy, I do not commit to the master branch - instead I merge the changes I make from my own branch.

So essentially, I'd make a branch, complete my changes, switch back to master to update it by running a `git pull`, and then merging my branch to the master branch.

The next part is a bit hazy to me. So a team member will then review my changes before the merge is actually carried out, and then I see the repository getting updated.

I thought running `git merge master` from my branch would instantly merge my branch with the master repository. Why is my coworker able to review the merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `git pull` you get all the contents from the remote repository and your master gets up to date with the contents in the remote repository. Assume your changes are in a branch named `test_branch` in your local repository where you have made your changes. Now you do a `git merge master` with your current branch being `test_branch` which means that your `test_branch` has all the changes in the remote repository plus your new changes to be reviewed. Your team member now reviews the difference between your local `master` branch and your `test_branch` which essentially gives the new changes you have made and that will be reviewed.